# Variables with the same name in nested functions

Tags: javascript

I'm reading You Don't Know JS, and the following example confuses me a little bit:

```
function foo () {
    function bar (a) {
        i = 3; // changing the `i` in the enclosing scope's for-loop
        console.log(a + i);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        bar(i * 2); // oops, infinite loop ahead!
    }
}

foo();
```

Wouldn't the engine look up (and stick to the assignment) of `i` inside the for loop, since it's declared and inside the scope of `foo`?

Why would it go to the `i` inside of bar?

Furthermore, even if `i`'s value was reassigned to 3, wouldn't it still go up one every time, thus avoiding the infinite loop?

Comment: The `i` inside of `bar()` is the same one as the `i` inside of `foo()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `bar`'s `i` is not declared with `var`, it uses the first `i` it can find in an outer scope: `foo`'s `i`. So this happens:

1. The `for` loop sets `i` to `0`.
2. `bar(0);` sets `i` to `3`.
3. The `for` loop increments `i` from `3` to `4`.
4. `bar(8);` sets `i` to `3`...

Steps 3 and 4 repeat endlessly, since `i<10` is always `true`.

(This sort of thing is why I don't like JavaScript.)

Comment: Thank you. But, if execution is from top to bottom (except async, etc), wouldn´t the for loop rewrite the value of i? Sorry, I´m trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @HernanAriel Execution isn't top to bottom. Each statement is _usually_ followed by the next. But functions cause execution to jump to somewhere else, `for` loops cause execution to jump to the top of the `for` loop... The `for` loop doesn't remember what number it got to; it just adds `1` to the current value of `i` and then checks to see if it's less than `10`.

Comment: I can tell you're new to programming. Might I suggest starting with a saner language than JavaScript? Like Python 3? I mean, JavaScript was one of _my_ first languages, but I messed around with Batch and Scratch before that so I got a general familiarity with the concepts. JavaScript's just got so much... bleh.

Comment: Hahaha, I wanna get into web development, so I can´t really avoid Javascript. So, just to sum up, the variables are hoisted (declared) before they are assigned a value? (So, that´s why bar i is the same as the i inside the for loop). One last question: does the for loop gets hoisted as well or not? Thanks!

Comment: Just functions declared with `function x() {}` and variables declared with `var` if I recall correctly?

Comment: @Caramiriel Correct.

Comment: @HernanAriel No; it's only `var`s and `function name() {}` declarations; not even the `x = 3;` part is hoisted.

Comment: @wizzwizz4,I thin in the fourth step of your answer,it need to be bar(8),like this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55260180/for-loop-infinite-loop-due-to-variable-collision

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has this concept of hoisting .. where you can use variable before they are declared. Before you code is executed javascript brings all declaring the variable statements to the top hence making the scope of i same inside for and bar.

you can read about hoisting here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp