# for-loop infinite loop due to variable collision

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Can anybody explain to me how this casue an infinite loop? I got this from an example of a javascript book.

The code is as follows:

```
function foo() {
  function bar(a) {
    i = 3; // changing the `i` in the enclosing scope's for-loop
    console.log( a + i );
  }
  for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    bar( i * 2 ); // oops, inifinite loop ahead!
  }
}
foo();
```

Comment: Well, you change `i` variable so you never reach the terminal condition `i<10`. Which part of this is unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you're changing `i` from the for-loop inside your `bar` function

```
i = 3;
```

That means outside of `bar` it can't reach the condition `i < 10`.

So the calls of `bar` would be like:

1. `bar(0 * 2);` then `i = 3;` then `console.log(0 + 3);` then `i++`
2. `bar(4 * 2);` then `i = 3;` then `console.log(8 + 3);` then `i++`
3. `bar(4 * 2);` then `i = 3;` then `console.log(8 + 3);` then `i++`
4. and so on... `i` will stay smaller than 10

You should change your code to avoid the set of `i = 3;`, which is the root of your problem.

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much! Understood it instantly when u explain like this. 
I misunderstood this as I thought `var i=0; i<10; i++` is in its own scope. Hence, the `i = 3;` would not cause it to change value.  

Thanks so much!

Comment: If it would be in its own scope the call of `i = 3;` would lead to an undefined error since you never introduced `i` before.

Comment: Oh right. Yet another learning point. Thanks so much! 

Thanks for bothering to explain such a simple question!

Comment: Always happy to help!

Comment: @BreakBB "*the call of `i = 3`; would lead to an undefined error*" - correction, that would create a global unless you are in strict mode - in *that* case, assigning to an undeclared variable throws a RefenceError instead of making an implied global.