# Why is this first line not a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Getting an error that this is not a arr is not a function but I can't understand why

```
var sumArray = function(arr) {
    total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        total =+ arr(i);
        return total;
    };
};

var arr = [1, 2, 3];
```

Comment: which line gives the error?

Comment: the variable i in the line 4 should use square brackets instead of round brackets.

Comment: `arr is not a function` - correct, it is an Array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`arr` is an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), so you need to indicate each element like `array[i]`

```js
var sumArray = function(arr) {
    var total = 0; //<---- missing `var` keyword
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ //<---- missing `var` keyword
        total += arr[i]; //<---- indicate arr[i], OP update from =+ to +=
    };
    return total; //<----- should be return after for loop finish.
};

var arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(sumArray(arr))
```

Comment: For the OP: Note the change from `=+` to `+=`.

Comment: Also mention the undeclared variables (`var total = 0;` and `for(var i = 0;`), which are not errors but are bad practice and may cause [hard to debug errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55260180/9867451) sometimes.

Comment: thanks @ibrahimmahrir i updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this, I'm very new to it all